# Emacs C-l command only recenters screen, and doesn't cycle through top and bottom repositioning

Tags: emacs, elisp, text-editor

Repeatedly running the emacs command `C-l` on my machine does not cycle through the three positions, only the first position (center of screen).

From the [GNU Emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recentering.html):

> **C-l (recenter-top-bottom)**
>
> Scroll the selected window so the current line is the center-most text
>   line; on subsequent consecutive invocations, make the current line the
>   top line, the bottom line, and so on in cyclic order. Possibly
>   redisplay the screen too (recenter-top-bottom).
>
> Typing C-l twice in a row (C-l C-l) scrolls the window so that point
>   is on the topmost screen line. Typing a third C-l scrolls the window
>   so that point is on the bottom-most screen line. Each successive C-l
>   cycles through these three positions.

When I run `C-l`, it only scrolls the window so that the current line is at the center-most text line. But upon subsequent invocations, the command just keeps recentering the window at the same point. I've used emacs on other machines where the cycling works, and the 2nd and 3rd iterations do scroll the window to the top-most and bottom-most lines, so I know there's something wrong with my version.

How can I fix this?

(Please let me know in the comments what files or information you need to see in order to diagnose the problem.)

Comment: What Emacs plugins do you have installed, if any?

Comment: @echristopherson Had this sass-mode plugin installed, but just rm'ed it, as I wasn't using it. (https://github.com/nex3/sass-mode/blob/master/sass-mode.el)

Comment: Which Emacs version are you using? This functionality was introduced in Emacs 23.1; earlier versions behave just like you describe.

Comment: Emacs 22 is many years old. If you're not planning to upgrade (you should probably upgrade), then you should be wary of relying on online documentation like this. Emacs is *self-documenting*, so you can always ensure you are getting appropriate information by making use of the in-built manuals and help (which is very useful for everyone, but even more so in your situation).

Comment: I upgraded before even finishing reading legoscia's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @legoscia mentioned, I added this command to Emacs in release 23.

But you can get the original, which works with all Emacs versions, by loading library [`misc-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/misc-cmds.el).  Or just grab the code for functions `recenter-top-bottom*` from there, if you do not want the other commands defined there.

Comment: @Markus: Works for me. Did you try starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If it works in that case then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Oops, I deleted my comment before I saw your reply because the function "recenter-top-bottom" does work for me when I bind a key to it and use the keybinding. But without the keybinding, doing `M-x recenter-top-bottom` directly doesn't work for me, i.e., it only centers, but doesn't do bottom or top.

Comment: @Markus: The cycling relies on the previous command being the same one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your init.el file

```
(setq recenter-positions '(middle top bottom))
```

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recentering.html

Comment: I put this in my `~/.emacs` file, which is the default init file, and this didn't seem to change anything. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Is your .emacs file properly loaded? Can you try `M-x eval-expression` then `recenter-positions` and tell me what you get?

Comment: It returned `(middle top bottom)`.

Comment: Then, when I evaluate `(middle top bottom)`, I get `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function middle)`

Comment: OK. So your `recenter-positions` value is properly set. Then can you start emacs with `emacs --no-init-file`, and type the following commands: `M-x set-variable` then `recenter-positions`, then `(middle top bottom)`. If your `C-l` does not rotate around middle, top, and bottom cursor positions, then your emacs does not support this function (or if you are using this on a terminal or ssh, your `C-l` may be intercepted by a shell, but I doubt it.) If it works, then one of your installed elisp packages does something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was introduced in Emacs 23.1.  In earlier versions, `C-l` behaved just like you describe: it always recenters the buffer, never cycles between top and bottom.

From the "Emacs 22 Antinews" section of the Emacs 23 manual:

> For those users who live backwards in time, here is information about downgrading to Emacs version 22.3.
>
> ...
>
> `C-l` now runs recenter instead of recenter-top-bottom. This always sets the current line at the center of the window, instead of cycling through the center, top, and bottom of the window on successive invocations. This lets you type `C-l C-l C-l C-l` to be absolutely sure that you have recentered the line.